# Правильно писать раздельно или слитно: «Елена все так же болела»?

Tags: союзы, частицы

1. Елена все **так же** болела.
2. Елена все **также** болела.

То есть подразумевается, что ранее в тексте упоминалась болезнь Елены. Я склоняюсь к первому варианту, так как подразумеваю сравнение: «Елена все так же болела, как и вчера». Однако я не могу найти нужного правила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Иногда выбрать форму письма не так просто, надо учитывать **смысл сказанного**, а не только правила. Простая проверка (также = тоже) не всегда определяет решение. Я полагаю, что при значении **"всё также = по-прежнему, как и раньше"** написание должно быть слитным (всё также).

Елена всё также болела (всё болела, по-прежнему болела).

Сравнить: Елена всё так же (= так тяжело) болела. Здесь "так" определяет степень признака.

Сравнить:

Мой взгляд скользнул по изгороди, на которой всё также сидел кот (по-прежнему).

Мой взгляд скользнул по изгороди, на которой всё так же сидел кот (в той же позе). Здесь на местоимение "так" ставится ударение.

2. **Розенталь**  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=73

Часто **только в условиях широкого контекста** можно различить наличие в предложении союза или сочетания (тоже — то же, также — так же). Ср.:

Остальные тоже громко кричали (‘и остальные громко кричали’).

Остальные то же громко кричали (‘громко кричали то же самое’).

Подростки также отважно боролись с фашистскими оккупантами (‘и подростки принимали участие в борьбе с фашистскими оккупантами’ — с интонационной паузой после слова также).

Подростки так же отважно боролись с фашистскими оккупантами (‘с такой же отвагой боролись’ — с интонационной паузой после слова отважно).

3. Вот **цитаты из современной литературы:**

Оба к утру были измучены и **все также** безысходно влюблены. [Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009)]

Над дорогой поднялось облако пыли... на земле росла груда развороченных тел, и только человек, **все также** улыбаясь, вздымал навстречу атакующим свой посох. [Виктор Пелевин. S.N.U.F.F (2011)

Comment: Спасибо за этот развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется, **Елена все так же болела.**
Также = тоже.